# Are regular expressions an example of logic programming?

Tags: regex, prolog, logic-programming

I'm just wondering if regular expressions fit into the definition of what Logic Programming is. It is a set of rules which given a set of facts yields a result depending on how the query is asked. To me that sounds like it should fall under Logic Programming but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the `prolog` tag?

Comment: Who need regexs? We have the [tag:dcg]-formalism, which covers context-free languages and beyond!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are finite state machines an example of imperative programming?

Regular expressions and logic programs definitely have one thing in common: Both have a natural **declarative** reading, and you can readily ask and answer:

> **What** is being described?

Using a sufficiently expressive logic programming language (and Prolog definitely falls in that category), it is easy to describe what a given regular expression means.

However, you will need some serious extensions to regular expressions in order to obtain a Turing-complete programming language or even something going beyond just regular languages.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is a domain-specific language. It doesn't specify *how* the matching is to occur, just *that* it will occur, so it is in that sense declarative--and there are two competing ways to implement a regular expression engine, NFA and DFA. Indeed, one of those is "non-deterministic finite automata," which is an aspect of declarative programming, especially Prolog. In both cases it really only has to do with backtracking, but the domain of regular expressions is so limited there is almost no meaningful correspondence there.

While you can get into semantics about finite automata, ultimately nobody uses regular expressions to express general computations with state, they only use them strictly as a DSL for string matching within other languages. So it is declarative in the sense of "here is a generic query" and most systems will do something sensible with it.

Prolog is obviously a lot more powerful than regular expressions, but I can see your train of thought and I think there is an analogy there, even if it isn't perfect.